# When I run the command to build ionic app: ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose. I get the following error:

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I run the command to build ionic app: ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose.
I get the following error:

ERROR in : 'IonInput' is not a known element:

1. If 'IonInput' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

```
(">Please enter the ip address of the server running machine</h3>
  <h2>Example 192.168.0.118 </h2>
  [ERROR ->]<IonInput value="custom" [(ngModel)]="ip_address"></IonInput>
  <IonButton (click)="ipSave()" color="")
```

: 'IonButton' is not a known element:

1. If 'IonButton' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

```
("  <h2>Example 192.168.0.118 </h2>
  <IonInput value="custom" [(ngModel)]="ip_address"></IonInput>
  [ERROR ->]<IonButton (click)="ipSave()" color="primary">Save</IonButton>
</ion-content>
")
```

src/app/layout/touring/touring.page.html(8,18): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read the Documentation. `<IonInput>, <IonIcon>`  etc is for React based application. if you are using Angular you should use `<ion-input></ion-input> or <ion-icon><ion-icon> `

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing React Tags with Angular Directives.   With your error message, I can safely assume your using Ionic/Angular.   Make sure you are following the Angular Documentation.